# Why is my URL changing when I try to fetch Weather Data from OpenWeatherMap API?

Tags: swift, xcode, model, nsurlrequest, http-method

I know, I have structured the model correctly based on the JSON data given. And composed the URLRequest correctly, I think, 90% positive. But for some reason, when I run my app and try to make a request it changes my url, to be specific... Right Below

> Here is the full URL I get back, but it changes the **"?"** symbol to **%3F** instead.

`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather%3Flat=40.866607666015625&lon=-73.99028259504165&appid=APIKEY <- omitted for safety.`

> Here is my original **URLRequest** format. Looking closely at, **/data/2.5/weather?lat=(latitude)&lon=(longitude)&(apiKey)**. I have omitted the apikey due to posting on stackoverflow. So don't worry about that.

```
enum WeatherService: ServiceProtocol {

    case currentLocation(Double, Double)

    var baseURL: URL {
        return URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org")!
    }

    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case let .currentLocation(latitude, longitude):
            return "/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(latitude)&lon=\(longitude)&\(apiKey)"
        }

    }

    var apiKey: String {
        return "appid=blahblahblah" <--- Ignore, because its an example post for stackoverflow
    }

    var method: HTTPMethod {
        return .get
    }
}
```

> Can anyone tell me the reason, am I actually formatting this  wrong?

Comment: I have figured it out. After "?" is not actually a path component so its better to be added as URLQueryItem

Comment: It's missing the code where you are using it. Calling baseURL & path. Where did you percent escaped the url ?